# How to nest routes in Akka HTTP?

Tags: scala, akka-http

I'm trying to write a simple series of routes, here's what I want to happen:

`GET /` should print "hello get"

`POST /` should print "hello post"

`GET /foo` should print "hello foo get"

`POST /foo` should print "hello foo get"

Here's what I have:

```
val route = pathSingleSlash {
    get(complete("hello get")) ~
    post(complete("hello post"))~
    path("foo") {
      get(complete("hello foo get"))~
      post(complete("hello foo post"))
    }
  }
```

This works for `GET /` and `POST /` but both GET and POST on `/foo` 404.

I've tried almost everything and can't figure out what to do. The documentation is pretty hard to understand when it comes to this.

Can anyone give me any pointers?

Comment: path matches value to the fool path, try to use pathPrefix instead of path

Answer (score 2, accepted):

can you please try this. it is working for me.

```
val route1 = path("foo") {
        get(complete("hello foo get")) ~
          post(complete("hello foo post"))
      }

  val route = pathSingleSlash {
    get(complete("hello get")) ~
      post(complete("hello post"))
  }

  val finalRoute = route ~ route1
```

and use finalRoute in your route binding statement.

```
val bindingFuture = Http().bindAndHandle(finalRoute, "localhost", 8085)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend structuring the paths this way for maximum readability:

```
get & pathEndOrSingleSlash {
  complete("hello get")
} ~
post & pathEndOrSingleSlash {
  complete("hello post")
} ~
get & path("foo") & pathEndOrSingleSlash {
  complete("hello foo get")
}
post & path("foo") & pathEndOrSingleSlash {
  complete("hello foo post")
}
```

Comment: I guess readability is subjective :P But good to know the options, thanks.

Comment: Also it doesn't work because `path` and `pathSingleSlash` do not compose. `get & path("foo")` should be enough anyway.